# MuleSoft + IBM MQ connection

Tags: mule, ibm-mq, mule-studio, mule-component

I have been trying to create an application that can send XML data into the Queue that I have created in IBM MQ and be able to browse the queue length and the messages available. I am not finding good tutorials to the do that. All this has to be achieved using MuleSoft ESB. I hope someone can help me in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

Start with [WMQ Example](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.5/websphere-mq-example) and che, the [WMQ Transport Reference](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/mule-wmq-transport-reference). That transport hasn't changed much since 3.5, so, it should work with newer Mule versions.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration of WMQ with mule is easy i've done it for wmq 7.5 version give port(default 1414)and it's varies for different Queue manager you can check in dos for WMQ connector

Answer (score 0):

find the link given which can help you to config IBM MQ with Mule

https://www.ricston.com/blog/websphere-mq-mule/

if you put WMQ as out bound you can able to send the xml to youe queue